# How to create simple Glow effect with PixelBender

Tags: flash, shader, glow, pixel-bender

I would like to add a glow effect in my flashgame like in "Geometry Wars"
[image]

I thought that must be possible with Pixelbender but I totally suck at this tool/language to write such a shader.

Did someone know how to do it or have maybe a good reference that can tell me how to achieve it?